# Visual studio 2012: Export history of a set of variable values to excel, csv e.t.c

Tags: c++, excel, csv, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a C++ project and I need to monitor a numerical recipe's convergence (it contains for and while loops), so I've input a few break points and dropped a few variables of interest in the watch panel, during debuging.

Would it be possible to export the whole history, i.e. every value each variable was assigned  ever during each loop, without having to do this by hand (copy paste at each break point).

Is there such a functionality in VS 2012?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do this with couts. Excel supports CSV http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: Thanks! that seems like the way to go